# Access control path and grant check

Tags: symfony

I do not unterstand so completly. In my app i have different controllers. Each controller action check if the user is granted to access the action, like.

```
$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_EDITOR')
```

If i define in my security.yml as access control path this line:

```
 - { path: ^/user/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
```

I feel that is so redundant. Is this the same logic? If this was the same, which one is faster or which one do you recommend me to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use (into `security.yml`)

```
- { path: ^/user/add, roles: ROLE_EDITOR }
```

because it will denied access at kernel request level(before controller events) so better to use firewall.

IF you use `$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_EDITOR')` in controller than it will not used code because it already denied from firewall.

Comment: I've used both, now i must modify my app. Many thanks for your support

Comment: I know it's quite late for an addition, but for other people reading it - I would suggest to use BOTH in some cases, why? The performance hit is negligible, but if you ever decide to change your paths and don't have unit tests covering security aspect, your controllers are accessible for everyone, e.g. for administration panels / CMS systems.